# Using VBScript to determine the logged on user

Tags: file, text, vbscript, desktop

Ok, so I want to make a program that creates a text file on the user's desktop, But I also want it to work on more than just my computer, Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so heres what I got:

```
Set File = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set User = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set Report = File.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\" & User.UserName & "\Desktop\Report.txt", True)
```

And if you want to type in something to the file say the date and time add this after the first three lines:

```
Report.WriteLine(vbNewLine & "Accessed On: " & Day(date) & "/" & Month(date) & "/" & Year(date) & vbNewLine & "Accessed At: " & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now))
Report.Close
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you've already accepted an answer from @Jonco98. However, there's no guarantee that `C:\Users` will always be the root user folder. On XP, it may be under `Documents and Settings`. Or, the OS may be installed on a drive letter other than `C`.

A better way to retrieve the user's desktop is by using the `WshSpecialFolders` collection.

```
strDesktopFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

Comment: you have my interest, after that would the code the same as what I put or what. What would change?

Comment: @Jonco98 Yep, I think the rest of your answer looks good. I would just replace `"C:\Users\" & User.UserName & "\Desktop\Report.txt"` with `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Report.txt"`.